# How to default the root view controller to landscape with a size of 1024x768

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, landscape

I'm developing an iPad app that needs to be restricted to landscape mode. I've got a root view controller
and a subview controller. I add the sub view controller to the root view controller and set their
frames to 1024x768. I restricted the app to landscape mode in info.plist and in my view controllers'
`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation` method. However, the dimensions for
the subview get reset to 768x1024 sometime before the `viewDidAppear` method which makes it appear 
as if it's in portrait mode.

The **strange** part is if I set the frame for the subview so that the width or height are something
other than the screen dimensions, for example: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 767) or CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 769), it doesn't get reset and
displays in what looks like landscape mode.

So my question is, what's causing this behavior. And what's the best way to simply default all views
to landscape mode

Here's my root view controller:

```
// INTERFACE

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ScrapViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    ScrapViewController *svc;
}
@end


// IMPLEMENTATION

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    svc = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
    svc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    svc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    [self.view addSubview:svc.view];

    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad rvc %f,%f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad svc %f,%f", svc.view.frame.size.width, svc.view.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

@end
```

Here's my sub view controller

```
// INTERFACE

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SubViewController : UIViewController

@end


// IMPLEMENTATION

@implementation SubViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

@end
```

Comment: just file a bug. This should be one.

Answer (score 0):

if you uses xib files then just make your subview's xib to represent it as landscape by default ie the default design of nib file will be landscap ie make your subview's view landscap in property window

Comment: Hi Aalok. In my quest for a landscaped subview I also tried creating a .xib to correspond to the sub view controller in which it was set to landscape. I instantiated it with `initWIthNibName:bundle` and it achieved the same effect. When it was set to 1024x768 the width/height were swapped but when it was 1024x769 it worked. I got it to work by resetting the frame in sub view controller's `viewDidAppear` method, but this seems like it should be unnecessary. I'm stymied.